Good alternatives to Hockey tape?
My nephew asked for hockey stick tape for christmas, but 12$ a roll on amazon its kinda dumb.
I've been out of the world of hockey for a long time so I dont know what to pick instead.
What other types of tape would be close to it without actually taking the one mentionning hockey that probably inflates the price just for that? Masking tape? Medical tape?

Athletic Tape is a great alternative as it’s similar in texture and adhesive strength to hockey tape. It’s often cheaper and can be found at most sports stores or online.
